# Varien File Uploader how to upload multiple files

Tags: varien-file-uploader

Varien_File_Uploader I need to know how to upload multiple files, received with different name.

ex:

1-->

```
<input name="userfile" type="file">
```

2-->

```
<input name="coverimage" type="file">
```

my current code is able to receive only one file.

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']) && $_FILES['userfile']['name'] != '') {
        try {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('userfile');
            echo 'testing';
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('png', 'jpg','gif'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()); 
            $folder_name_date = date('Y_m_d', $currentTimestamp);
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $folder_name_date;
            if(!is_dir($path)){
                mkdir($path, 0777, true);
            }
            $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['userfile']['name'] );             
            $newFilename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
            echo $path. DS .$newFilename;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'File is not set';
    }
```

Comment: use `foreach` loop.

Comment: :D any other way. Varien_File_Uploader inbuild method?

Comment: why do you want to make things complex. just go on with foreach loop. That is the solution for this. There is no "Magento Way" of doing this. So go on with "PHP Way"

Comment: otherwise you have to repeat your whole code for other file type :), do you want to add some thing more in your query i am eager know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento uses `Varien_File_Uploader` to upload files within the system. When you want to upload multiple files, then use above class in a `foreach` loop. As far as I know, there is no "Magento way" for uploading multiple files. So go on with "PHP Way". ie use a `foreach` loop. This is an example

```
$_files = array(
    'userfile' => array(
        'allowed_extensions' => array('png', 'jpg', 'gif'),
        'rename_file'        => true,
        'file_dispersion'    => true,
        'file_path'          => 'path/to/the/file'
    ),
    'coverimage' => array(
        'allowed_extensions' => array('png', 'jpg', 'gif'),
        'rename_file'        => true,
        'file_dispersion'    => true,
        'file_path'          => 'path/to/the/file'
    )
);
foreach ($_files as $filename => $fileOpt) {
    if (isset($_FILES[$filename]['name']) && $_FILES[$filename]['name'] != '') {
        try {
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($filename);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array($fileOpt['allowed_extensions']));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles($fileOpt['rename_file']);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion($fileOpt['file_dispersion']);
            //$currentTimestamp = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()); 
            //$folder_name_date = date('Y_m_d', $currentTimestamp);
            //$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $folder_name_date;
            if(!is_dir($fileOpt['file_path'])){
                mkdir($path, 0777, true);
            }
            $uploader->save($fileOpt['file_path'], $_FILES[$filename]['name'] );             
            $newFilename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
            echo $fileOpt['file_path']. DS .$newFilename;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'File is not set';
    }
}
```